# SQL Distinct clause not working?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, distinct

I'm new to SQL so sorry if this is me being stupid!

I am trying to select a few columns where the name does not appear more than once, however using the distinct clause does not do this for some reason?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.fldContactName, A.fldsignonlinesetup, B.fldorderdate, A.fldemail
FROM tblcustomers AS A
LEFT JOIN tblorders AS B ON A.fldcustomerid = B.fldcustomerid
WHERE B.fldorderdate BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
AND A.fldemail <> 'NULL' AND A.fldcontactname <> 'NULL' AND A.fldcontactname <> '' 
AND A.fldemail <> ''
AND A.fldsignonlinesetup = 0
ORDER BY A.fldcontactname ASC
```

How do I get it to only show records that are unique e.g. contact name John Smith only comes up once?

Expected Outcome:

```
fldContactName:    fldEmail:        fldSignOnlineSetup:    fldOrderDate:
James Smith        Email1@gmail.com         0              2016-08-14
Bill Plant         Email2@gmail.com         0              2015-02-24
```

Actual Outcome:

```
fldContactName:    fldEmail:        fldSignOnlineSetup:    fldOrderDate:
James Smith        Email1@gmail.com         0              2016-08-14
Bill Plant         Email2@gmail.com         0              2015-02-24
James Smith        Email1@gmail.com         0              2014-06-20
```

Comment: Provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: Do you really mean `fldemail <> 'NULL'` or do you intend `A.fldemail IS NOT NULL`?  Your version is a string comparison to a string with four letters.  The second checks that the value is not `NULL`.

Comment: Distinct is distinct on all fields not just one. If you want just one record per name to show up then you must know the business rules that let you exclude related records or you need to concatenate the values of related records into one field, Since peopel likely have more than one order, it is unlikely that you will ever have only one line pername and meet your business rules, unless they want only the first order or the most recent order.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want it to filter out results that are NULL value

Comment: @HLGEM I just need to find the contacts name and email that meet the criteria, however there are many orders from the same people.

Comment: Why not `James Smith        Email1@gmail.com         0              2014-06-20` instead?

Comment: @Strawberry It doesn't matter which one it chooses, im just trying to simplify it so that only one of the results comes up. I basically don't want one person to come up more than once.

Comment: If it doesn't matter, that sometimes points to a flaw in your data model. It *should* matter!

Comment: @MattEllis, it might not matter to you, but it likely will to your users. That is why this is a business rule issue. If you don't need the orders, then don't select the field. If the users want that field, then THEY must specify which of the multiple records you need to show them via a business rule.  If they didn't want the order information,they wouldn't be asking for it. You not only should know what they are asking for but what they intend to do with the data so that you can give them the correct data. Just getting one record person is not enough to know you have the correct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the naming only appearing once, then `group by` comes to mind.  One method is:

```
SELECT c.fldContactName,
       MAX(c.fldsignonlinesetup) as fldsignonlinesetup,
       MAX(c.fldorderdate) as fldorderdate,
       MAX(c.fldemail) as fldemail
FROM tblcustomers c LEFT JOIN
     tblorders o
     ON c.fldcustomerid = o.fldcustomerid
WHERE o.fldorderdate BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2016-12-31' AND
      c.fldemail <> 'NULL' AND c.fldcontactname <> 'NULL' AND 
      c.fldcontactname <> '' AND c.fldemail <> '' AND
      c.fldsignonlinesetup = 0
GROUP BY c.fldcontactname
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY c.fldcontactname ASC;
```

`SELECT DISTINCT` just makes sure that *all* the columns in the result set are never duplicates.  It has nothing to do with finding values with only one row.  The `HAVING` clause does this.

Notes:

- The use of table aliases is good, but abbreviations for table names make the query more understandable.
- The `MAX()` is really a no-op.  With one row, it returns the value from the one row.
- The `GROUP BY` is on the field you care about -- the one you don't want duplicates for.
- The `HAVING` clause gets the values with only one row.
- MySQL does not require the `MAX()` functions, but I strongly recommend using an aggregation function, so you don't learn bad habits that don't work in other databases and can behave unexpected in MySQL.
- Do you really mean `fldemail <> 'NULL'` or do you intend `A.fldemail IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: Note to the OP, this may or may not give you what you need. It really depends on your business rules which only your particular business can define.

Comment: Thank you for your help however, when running this query it says that there is an invalid column name 'fldorderdate'?

Comment: probably needs to be `o.fldorderdate` in the `SELECT` list instead of `c.`

Comment: Also, this will exclude the record for `James Smith` from the results, just remove `HAVING` clause if you want 1 record per whether it has more than 1 or not.

Comment: @HartCO . . . This was in response to "I am trying to select a few columns where the name does not appear more than once".  I do admit, however, that the question is rather ambiguous.

Comment: "The use of table aliases is good" - I hold the opposite view! What you call 'table aliases' are range variables. You only need them for pre-1992 join types that produce duplicate column names.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to display your selected data only once or get only the data that is unique in the DB?

For the latter do

```
SELECT A.fldContactName, A.fldsignonlinesetup, B.fldorderdate, A.fldemail
FROM tblcustomers AS A
LEFT JOIN tblorders AS B ON A.fldcustomerid = B.fldcustomerid
WHERE B.fldorderdate BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
AND A.fldemail not in ('NULL', '') 
AND A.fldcontactname not in ('NULL', '')
AND A.fldsignonlinesetup = 0
GROUP BY A.fldContactName, A.fldsignonlinesetup, B.fldorderdate, A.fldemail
HAVING count(*) = 1
ORDER BY A.fldcontactname ASC
```